# Why electron-app it's not working in production env?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, electron, azure-ad-msal

I have an application which I have used the [@azure/msal-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-node) authentication Library for Node JS
everything works well on *localhost env* when I click to `login` it took me to a web page in browser to enter credentials and when I came back to the application authorized me to use the app as expected.
**BUT** when I build with `npm run electron-builder` and access the application from `.exe` it took me to a web page and even if I do my same credentials and return back to the application it still in home page which means I am not authorized to use the app.
I think the problem came from this block of code:

```js
// Event handlers
ipcMain.on(IPC_MESSAGES.LOGIN, async () => {
  const account = await authProvider.login(); //<- stop here and didn't complete to the next line
  await mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "./form.html"));
  mainWindow.webContents.send(IPC_MESSAGES.SHOW_WELCOME_MESSAGE, account);
});
```

```js
async login() {
    const authResponse = await this.getToken({
      // If there are scopes that you would like users to consent up front, add them below
      // by default, MSAL will add the OIDC scopes to every token request, so we omit those here
      scopes: ["------------------------------------------"],
    });

    var https = require("follow-redirects").https;
    var fs = require("fs");

    var options = {
      method: "GET",
      hostname: "----------------------------------",
      path: "------------------------------------",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authResponse.accessToken}`,
      },
      maxRedirects: 20,
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];

      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      res.on("end", function (chunk) {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      });

      res.on("error", function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
    });

    req.end();

    return this.handleResponse(authResponse);
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Were there any errors in the console of the renderer or the main process? if so, can you also share those for more context? Also, from the provided code, it isn't clear what and when`login` is supposed to return (function definition seems incomplete)

Comment: I've changed the technology completely